# Warning: session_id(): Cannot change session id when session is active

Tags: magento, php-7.3

After the server PHP version of my Magento 2.2.1 website was upgraded from 7.2 to 7.3, the following error was prompted:

```
Warning: session_id(): Cannot change session id when session is active in /home/customer/www/mysite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 514
```

How to solve it？

Need to solve this problem

Comment: Magento 2.2.1 and PHP 7.3 are too old. You might want to upgrade both to a supported version: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html. Don't forget to upgrade the MySQL as well.

Comment: Can modifying the code solve this problem?

Comment: Not suggested. Modifying Magento core codes might break the system and might hinder the capability of future version updates. You should upgrade Magento.